# ElasticSearch Issue With Matching Results

Tags: search, elasticsearch, match, matching, n-gram

I have an issue querying where if 'ford' is in the database and I search for 'fordddddddd' it returns a match. I have ngrams for sub partial matching for queries like 'fo', for', ford' but 'fordddddd' should not match. What could be the issue? Below are my setting, mappings, and query.

Settings:

```
  settings: {
    number_of_shards: 1,
    analysis: {
      filter: {
        ngram_filter: {
          type: 'edge_ngram',
          min_gram: 2,
          max_gram: 15
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        ngram_analyzer: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: [
            'lowercase',
            'ngram_filter'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Mappings:

```
  mappings: [
    {
      name: 'car',
      _all: {
        type: 'string',
        analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer'
      },
      properties: {
        description: {
          properties: {
            name: {
              type: 'string',
              include_in_all: true,
              term_vector: 'yes',
              analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer'
            },
            model: {
              type: 'string',
              include_in_all: true,
              term_vector: 'yes',
              analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer'
            }
          }
        }        
      }
    }
  ]
```

Query:

```
GET car/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
               "query": "Forddddddd"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are using the same `analyzer` for `indexing` and `searching`.

when you search for `Forddddd`, `ngram_analyzer` is applied and it generates tokens *fo, for, ford* and hence it gives you results, you should specify `standard analyzer` for searching and you will get desired results.

```
properties: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        include_in_all: true,
        term_vector: 'yes',
        analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
        search_analyzer: 'standard' <--- here
    },
    model: {
        type: 'string',
        include_in_all: true,
        term_vector: 'yes',
        analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
        search_analyzer: 'standard' <--- here
    }
}
```